# how to tell a typecast from a function

Tags: c, gtk

While practicing a tutorial on GTK+ I have encountered sample code that looks like this:

```
gtk_misc_set_alignment (GTK_MISC (label), 0, 0);
```

all of the authors code has a space between function and (), but so does the typecasts.
obviously gtk_misc_set_alignment() is a function, but how do I tell if
GTK_MISC (label) is a function or a typecast?

Sorry for the noob question, I am a noob programmer,
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should also read the documentation: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkMisc.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, `GTK_MISC` is a macro that hides a "classic" C typecast. It's probably something like:

```
#define GTK_MISC(p)    ((GtkMisc *)(p))
```

You could instead simply write:

```
gtk_misc_set_alignment ((GtkMisc *) label, 0, 0);
```

I don't know exactly why GTK provides such macros, maybe they like to "emulate" the "function-like" cast that C++ provides.

---

***Edit***

Ok, maybe I got it. I didn't find a specific documentation for `GTK_MISC`, but it seems to be exactly the same thing as [`G_OBJECT`](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#G-OBJECT:CAPS), which says:

> ```
> #define G_OBJECT(object)            (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST ((object), G_TYPE_OBJECT, GObject))
> ```
>
> Casts a `GObject` or derived pointer into a `(GObject*)` pointer. Depending on the current debugging level, this function may invoke certain runtime checks to identify invalid casts.

So, probably `GTK_MISC` too performs some runtime checks on the pointer to check if it can be actually casted to a `GtkMisk *`. You could say that it is somewhat the concept of `dynamic_cast` in C++.

Answer (score 5):

The typecast is done with the type inside parenthesis

```
( type ) object         // typecast
identifier ( argument ) // function call
```

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that  type (object) was not valid in C thank you for the fast response

Answer (score 4):

In C `type(value)` is not a valid cast. That's C++ syntax.

Comment: In GTK, these sorts of casts are macros, so they do look like that.

Answer (score 0):

GLib's, and so GTK's type system is a bit different from C's type system. GLib is developed in C, and as such, it can't have real classes like in C++, C# or Java. So they have to emulate it somehow. Each object is actually a struct (in this case, a struct _GtkMisc), which has a class field, which gets initialized when the type (class) is registered. The type casting macros check this field value, and if the "object" is inherited from the requested type (in this case, from GtkMisc), it is "typecasted" to that. If not, it will bark you an error, so if you are unsure, you can check it with GTK_IS_*() macros, like

```
if (GTK_IS_MISC(label))
    gtk_misc_set_alignment(label);
```

About the question's second part, the spaces before the braces are the part of the Gnome team's coding standards, which, as far as I know, is derived from the GNU Coding Standards.